# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in react

Tags: reactjs

In the register component after submitting the form, it shows an error like "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

I also have a backend

Here's the code

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
const Register = () => {
    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({
        displayName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const history = useNavigate();
    const { displayName, email, password } = userDetails;

  const handleRegister = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            return setError(`Passwords don't match`)
        }
       
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                displayName,
                email,
                password,
                confirmPassword
            })
        })

        const data = await response.json()

        if(data.status === 'ok') {
            history.push('/login');
        }

        console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused between the Router's version,

In React Router v6,

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function SignupForm() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await submitForm(event.target);
    navigate("../success", { replace: true });
  }

  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* ... */}</form>;
}
```

Refer: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate

In React Router v5,

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Refer: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 0):

In react router dom v6, you dont need to `history.push`.

WHat you can do is: `history("/login")`

**Not so imprtant**
A more relevant nomenclature will be:

```
const navigate = useNavigate(); //instead of history as a name
.
.
.
navigate('/login')
```